# How to store a PHP operator or expression in an XML node

Tags: php, xml, operators, expression

I'm a teacher making an answer key, and every so often a question has multiple possible correct answers.  How can I *simply* check whether a student's answer matches any one of  them?

I want to do something like this in my XML:

```
<answer>foo||bar</answer>
```

### PHP:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
$correctAnswer = $xml->answer;
if ($textEntered == $correctAnswer) {  echo 'Correct!';
```

Now if it were just`foo` (and not `||bar`), then this PHP code would work.   Is there a similar 1-string solution to enable multiple answers?  I'd rather not have to do tons of processing of child elements.

Comment: You're missing double quote in `file.xml`

Comment: Thanks!  (Fixed it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just need to explode the correct answer and then check for correctness differently.  Something like:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
$correctAnswer = explode('||', $xml->answer);
if ( in_array($textEntered, $correctAnswer) ) {  
    echo 'Correct!';
}
```

Note this will work for the case when you have only 1 correct answer because `explode()` always returns an array.  Even if the array has only 1 element.  Just make sure to choose a separator string that will never appear in an answer.

Comment: Oh gosh!  You just saved me from having to bulk up 48,000 lines of answer-key code.  Thanks!  (I'd forgotten about the explode function.)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches I would suggest depending on how complex the answers are. One is a token list, it works only if the answers can no contain whitespaces. An example are is the class attribute in HTML. That way it can be matched with Xpath expressions:

```
$answer = new SimpleXMLElement('<answer>foo bar</answer>');
var_dump(
  $answer->xpath('/answer[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(.), " "), " bar ")]')
);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "foo bar"
  }
}
```

SimpleXMLElement::xpath() always returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects. DOMXpath::evaluate() can directly return a boolean value.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml('<answer>foo bar</answer>');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate(
    'count(/answer[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(.), " "), " bar ")]) > 0'
  )
);
```

A better way that works with answers might be child elements:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml('<answer><_>foo</_><_>bar</_></answer>');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate(
    'count(/answer[(not(*) and . = "foo") or (* = "foo")]) > 0'
  )
);
```

- match answer nodes
  `/answer`
- that do not have element child nodes
  `/answer[not(*)]`
- and the text content is `foo`
  `/answer[(not(*) and . = "foo")]`
- or has an child element with the text content `foo`
  `/answer[(not(*) and . = "foo") or (* = "foo")]`